# syslog-ng read file permission denied

Tags: tomcat, selinux, syslog-ng

i need to send tomcat Catalina.out log content by Syslog-ng but 
but after restarting Syslog service ,it gets permission denied error

so how can i give a read access to Syslog-ng for read from CATALINA.out ?
"tomcat directory belongs to specific user and specific group so cannot be change."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's possible that your Selinux/apparmor profile doesn't allow syslog-ng  to access the file. See this blogpost for tips: https://syslog-ng.com/blog/using-syslog-ng-with-selinux-in-enforcing-mode/

Answer (score 1):

i have found my problem in /etc/apparmor.d/sbin.syslong-ng,,,,after editing and insert new permission to profile.  command # apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/profile.name reloads profile