# Syslog-ng - File permission error in suse Linux

Tags: suse, syslog-ng

I am getting the below given error when I try to forward certain log files using syslog-ng in Suse Linux

```
Starting syslog servicesError opening file for reading; filename='/tmp/app.log', error='Permission denied (13)'
```

my conf file - Source definition seems to be ok

```
source app {

file("/tmp/app.log");

};
```

I went through similar posts and dont see any problems with my steps.The weird part is that the file is owned by root and when i run syslog-ng as root it gives read permission error

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused because of **AppArmor** linux security module. Solution to this problem is mentioned in attached thread. [syslog-ng read file permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49025983/syslog-ng-read-file-permission-denied)

Here are steps I followed.

1. Open **/etc/apparmor.d/sbin.syslong-ng**
2. Add **/opt/xxx/logs/* rw,** line anywhere. **rw** below means allow read & write access. Change your directory appropriately.
3. Run **apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/sbin.syslong-ng** to set new rules.
4. Restart **syslog-ng** using service command or any other way you have set up.